# translate */AMP to *?AMP

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

I am trying to use regx in a WordPress redirect plugin that only change the last characters. The plugin uses PHP regular expressions: http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php

Anything ending with `/AMP`
Redirect to the same url but end it in `?AMP`

I'm trying

```
^/(.*)/AMP
```

to

```
/$1?AMP
```

But I know I've got something wrong here.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Please specify a programming language.

Comment: "But I know I've got something wrong here." What did you get? What did you expect? What language/tool are you using?

Comment: Of course. Sorry. It's a WordPress plugin that uses PHP regular expressions. I've modified the post.

Comment: Like this: `(^.*)\/(AMP$)` https://regex101.com/r/X8TyhK/1

Comment: Thanks that seems close but it seem to produce "/AMPa" as the output. Also i need to express it as two different fields. The first is the match and the second is what it returns.

Comment: I think i have it close. The following works. However for the root home page domain.com/amp then translates it to domain.com/amp?amp, In other words it all works except for the root domain which adds an extra amp at the end. My input source is    ^(.*)\/amp$ and my target translate is $1?amp

Answer (score 0):

I got some outside help and came up with this. Thanks for everyone's help, positive attitudes, and positive points. :-)

^([^?]*(?:/|^))amp$